# What's wrong with the face mesh?

Tags: mesh, faces

I've seen this before whenever I bend the bone joints sometimes there fine but other times the faces on the others clip in together and sometimes when I twist the joints at an even further angle, they either stay like that or they disappear. Is it a glitch? Or if not, how can I get rid of it?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have disconnected geometry. Sometimes, for whatever reason, geometry can become separated, but it still looks like it is joined together, until you start moving it around that is.

The easiest way to fix this problem is to use a free addon called **Machin3tools**. Its not hard to find with Google. Once you have it installed then go into edit mode, select all your geometry, and press `3` key and it should be fixed.

edit: By "fixed" I mean that all the geometry that is disconnected will be connected, or if it is just an orphaned vertices not connected to anything or overlapping with another vertices, or even an orphan edge or face not connected or overlapping with anything then it will just be deleted.

Comment: I double checked the vertices around the fingers of the hand, but I didn't find any loose geometry their all connected. But when I switch between wireframe mode and solid mode, they look so different.

Comment: I really suggest you just try the addon as I mentioned, if it doesn't work just disable the addon and forget about it. Here is an example of how it works, skip to timeline 4:20 to see how to deal with "non-manifold geometry".

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sGOjH-zqWd0